# Do you use power conditioning?

Tags: power

Using power conditioning?

What type and what for?

Either Studio or Field/Location rigs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a 10-year-old Furman power conditioner into which I've plugged an outboard rack synth or two, and my audio interface. (All computers and hard drives are on UPS's.) I do so as a hedge against variable juice from the grid during peak times or weather events (which creates brownouts sometimes in my neighborhood). I'm not sure that it, in Furman's words, "dramatically improves" my audio signal path, but it's a low cost to pay for more uniform voltage, which *might* be extending the life of my gear. But I'd have to do a multi-year A/B comparison to know for sure! Would love to know if anyone has more serious science around this.

Answer (score 3):

I recently upgraded the wiring for my home studio with two 20amp circuits. On the end of one I have an [APC](http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=SUa1500rm2u) and on the other line a [Tripplite](http://www.tripplite.com/en/products/model.cfm?txtSeriesID=937&txtModelID=2950). The APC has all the power supplies that can allow momentary interruption. The Tripplite has all the devices that need rock steady power. If you have the extra $$$ I would definitely recommend getting an "on-line" system like the Tripplite. The APC takes a second to kick over so passes momentary power loss. TheTripplite is a true on-line system and never lets the power drop even for a split second. The power in my area is constantly browning out or flickering on/off ... very annoying until I setup these units.

Comment: I have an APC as well. Works great for me. Allows me the opportunity to save and back out while the lights flicker. I usually don't like to work through power fluxes. Fortunately, they usually only come and go with thunderstorms.

Answer (score 2):

I had terrrible power in an old apt in Brooklyn.  Several pieces of gear went bad including a transformer on a 1968 fender Deluxe blackface.  The reason i know it was the power is that eventually i got a conditioner and 2 pieces of gear started to work again (1 was a CD changer, I dont remember what the other was.  it was 1991 or so).  Sadly, the blackface needed more work than I could afford...

Answer (score 1):

Sure do!  [SurgeX](http://www.surgex.com) is awesome when it comes to surge protection and power conditioning - no sacraficial parts, clean and regulated power.  They also have some great reading on the site about grounding and power conditioning for a/v systems.  They're not cheap, but they're worth it in my opinion.

Comment: SurgeX stuff is great heard goon news about them too